# Atmosphere GWT error

Tags: java, gwt

I try to run (without maven) the atmosphere-gwt20 demo found [here](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-samples/tree/master/extensions-samples/gwt/gwt20-rpc).

Java compile fine but, when I compile with gwt (2.5.1), I stumble in this error:

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'org/atmosphere/gwt20/client/AtmosphereRequestConfig.java'
[ERROR] Line 18: The import org.atmosphere.gwt20.shared cannot be resolved
[ERROR] Line 99: Constants cannot be resolved
```

My WEB-INF/lib contains

```
atmosphere-gwt20-client-2.0.0.jar
atmosphere-gwt20-common-2.0.0.jar
atmosphere-gwt20-server-2.0.0.jar
atmosphere-runtime-2.0.5.jar
gwt-servlet.jar
slf4j-api.1.6.1.jar
```

do I miss something?

Comment: I substitute each atmosphere-gwt20-..-2.0.0.jar with atmosphere-gwt-20-...-2.0.2.jar and gwt compile works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I substitute each atmosphere-gwt20-..-2.0.0.jar with atmosphere-gwt-20-...-2.0.2.jar and gwt compiles fine.